# Manifold contains a totally geodesic closed hypersurface

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M^n,g)$ be a closed simply-connected positively curved manifold. Show that if $M$ contains a totally geodesic closed hypersurface (i.e., the second fndamental form or shape operator is zero), then $M$ is homeomorpic to a sphere.

Answer (score 1):

If $H$ is a hypersurface, then we cut $M$ into two regions $D_i$ where $\partial D_i=H$ Then 
define $$ f : D_1\rightarrow {\bf R},\ f(p)=d(H,p)$$ where $d$ is a distance function.

If $c$ is a normal geodesic with $c(0)=p$, then $f\circ c(t)$ is concave. Since $M$ is positively curved so $f$ has a unique maximum so that by Morse theory $D_1$ is homeomorphic to a $n$-dimensional disk.